# Where will the EMF be induced?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

> A charged particle is kept at rest in a uniform magnetic field. If the magnetic field starts increasing with time, the charge will begin moving.

This is a statement in my textbook. 
I know that a changing magnetic field results in an induced EMF, which accounts for the electric field.
But I find it hard to imagine this situation in real life. I mean, there's no loop, no wire, where will the electric field be induced?
Perhaps on the Boundary of the magnetic field. But what if it's an infinite field?

Comment: Does your textbook give the *direction* of the movement that it predicts?

Comment: @Philip Wood No, this is the end of the paragraph.

Comment: I think that the absence of such a prediction should make you suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

This is the principle of the betatron : a variable magnetic field induces an electric field which accelerates charged particles.

[wikipedia : betatron](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Betatron)

Answer (score 0):

> But I find it hard to imagine this situation in real life. I mean, there's no loop, no wire, where will the electric field be induced?

Why do you think there's no loop or wire present?

We imagined a situation where there is a uniform magnetic field present. That field might be produced by a wire loop, or a solenoid, or a straight wire. Or it might be produced by a permanent magnet.

But the details of how it's produced aren't important. Regardless of what produces the magnetic field, if the field starts to change, the an electric field will be produced and the test charge will feel a force.

Even though the details of what source produces the magnetic field aren't important, you shouldn't assume there is *no* source for the magnetic field.

Comment: "if the field starts to change, the an electric field will be produced and the test charge will feel a force." In which direction will that force act?